# trying to add some link cell in my GWT cellTable

Tags: gwt

I am trying to add a Link in my cell table (I just want the item to be underlined and mouse symbol change on hover)

and on click I just want to give a window Alert .

for that i have tried these Options : ( but no luck )

1)

```
           final Hyperlink hyp  = new Hyperlink("test", "test");


    Column<EmployerJobs, Hyperlink> test = new Column<EmployerJobs, Hyperlink>(new HyperLinkCell())

    {
        @Override
        public Hyperlink getValue(EmployerJobs object)
        {
        return hyp;
        }
    };
```

Problem with option 1 is , it takes me to navigation page "test", whereas I dont want to go any other page i just want a window alert.

2)

```
         Column<EmployerJobs, SafeHtml> test = new Column<EmployerJobs, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell())
    {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(EmployerJobs object)
        {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            sb.appendEscaped("test");

                return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
```

problem with option 2 is I dont know what exactly to return here and its not getting underlined.

3) at last i am trying to add anchor in my celltable with a compositecell(as ideally i want three different anchors in my ONE cell)

```
final Anchor anc = new Anchor();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(anc);
     CompositeCell ancCell = new CompositeCell(list);
    Column testColumn1 = new Column<EmployerJobs, Anchor>(ancCell) {

        @Override
        public Anchor getValue(EmployerJobs object) {


            return anc;
        }       
    };
```

Option 3 is giving some exception .

If you can help me get working any of the above option, I'll be grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it totally wrong. You need to use [ActionCell](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html) for stuff like this or create your own cell. Example code:

```
    ActionCell.Delegate<String> delegate = new ActionCell.Delegate<String>(){ 
      public void execute(String value) { //this method will be executed as soon as someone clicks the cell
              Window.alert(value);

      } 
    };
    ActionCell<String> cell = new ActionCell<String>(safeHtmlTitle,delegate){

        @Override
        public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,  //we need to render link instead of default button
                String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a href='#'>");
            sb.appendEscaped(value);
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</a>");
        }
    }; 

    Column testColumn1 = new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(cell) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(EmployerJobs object) { 
            //we have to return a value which will be passed into the actioncell

            return object.name;
        }       
    };
```

I recommend to read official [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html) for Cell Widgets, since it is pretty much everything what you need to know about cell widgets.