# GWT: How can I add anchor cell in my CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

Any idea how can I add anchor in my `CellTable`? I found the same question here but couldn't get a working solution for that.

Could someone provide some working code for adding an anchor in a CellTable column?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043711/adding-hyperlink-in-gwt-celltable/9047295#9047295

Comment: the answers in this question were actioncell,button cell but not anchor , I mean my goal is to get some thing in my cell which is underlined and when we hover the mouse cursor changes as HREF ,isnt is possible to add some hred,hyper link onwhich when we click it just give us some window alert

Comment: possible duplicate of [trying to add some link cell in my GWT cellTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212695/trying-to-add-some-link-cell-in-my-gwt-celltable)

Comment: My answer is meant to point out that it isn't possible to draw an Anchor (a widget) in a CellTable (which draws cells). It is possible to draw an 'a href' tag with a cell, see the second paragraph. If you have questions about how to implement that, which appears to be exactly what you want, ask, post some sample code which doesn't quite work, and I'll be happy to try and help.

Answer (score 3):

The widget `Anchor` cannot be added into a `CellTable`, as all cell widgets only know how to draw `Cell<C>` instances. This lets them draw and redraw their content much more quickly/efficiently than they could do with `Widget`s.

A html anchor element, `<a href='someUrl'>text</a>` can be drawn easily as a `Cell`. Subclass `AbstractCell` and define the render method to draw this html, interleaved with any text or link that you want to redirect to. Then, when building the `CellTable`, pass this `Cell` instance into the `Column` constructor.

Take a look at some of the existing `Cell`s in GWT to see how else you can draw things (like `ButtonCell.render` makes a button instead of an a), or how to handle events (`AnchorCell` on how to handle a click programmaticly instead of letting the a redirect to a new page, or `TextInputCell` for a more complex example).

Answer (score 2):

I like using [`SafeHtmlCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SafeHtmlCell.html) to render Widget's HTML into `CellTable`:

```
Column<MyTableType, SafeHtml> anchorColumn = new Column<MyTableType, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {
    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(MyTableType object) {
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(...);
        return SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(anchor.toString());
    }
};
```

Note that `Widget.toString();` returns Widget's HTML snippet meant to be viewed in the debugger. It will not contain any handlers nor listeners. It will be just HTML, but it is just enough to render simple things in the `CellTable`.